# Unable to add trigger in MySql/Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, triggers, check-constraints

I am creating a table (using MySql 8.0) where I want to add the CHECK constraint on two columns (say column1 and column2). As CHECK constraint is not available in MySql I have created an before insert trigger. Below is the MySql query for adding the trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `database_name`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `database_name`.`table_name_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.column1 = NULL AND NEW.column2 = NULL)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'column1 and column2 both cannot be null';
    ELSEIF (NEW.column1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column2 IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'column1 and column2 both cannot have a value';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

While running this script I am getting error **Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)**. The user which I am using has trigger privileges. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has created a guide for how to enable triggers for an Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance. It is located here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

This is from the guide:

How can I enable functions, procedures, and triggers for my Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) MySQL DB instance?

Amazon RDS is a managed service, and it doesn't provide SYS access (SUPER privileges). If binary logging is enabled on your MySQL DB instance, set the log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter to true in the custom DB parameter group that you create for your DB instance. For more information, see the Master user account privileges for Amazon RDS.

If you create a DB instance without specifying a DB parameter group, Amazon RDS creates a new default DB parameter group. For more information, see Working with DB parameter groups.

1. Create a DB parameter group.
2. Modify the DB parameter group as follows: log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
3. Choose Save Changes.
   Note: Before using the DB parameter group with a DB instance, wait at least 5 minutes.
4. From the navigation pane, choose Databases.
5. Choose the DB instance that you want to associate with the DB parameter group.
6. Choose Actions and choose Modify.
7. Select the parameter group that you want to associate with the DB instance.
8. Reboot the DB instance.

   Note: The parameter group name is changed immediately, but the parameter group changes aren't applied until you reboot the instance without failover.

When automated backup is enabled for a MySQL DB instance, it also enables binary logging. You might receive the following error message when creating a trigger: "ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)"

If you receive this error, modify the log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter to 1 to allow functions, procedures, and triggers on your DB instance.